# My ObjectOutputStream isn't working properly

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server

I'm trying to make multiplayer game with java, and I'm stuck with sending objects through object stream and receiving it properly.
From Server, I send **Snake** object and **Apple** object to Client using ObjectOutputStream. Server and Client are threads running in different program.

This is code for Server, sending objects to Client.

```
//clientSocket[i] = Socket object connected with Client
objectOutputStreams[i] = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket[i].getOutputStream());
...

//Sending ArrayList<Snake> to Client
objectOutputStreams[i].writeObject(snake);
objectOutputStreams[i].flush();

//Sending Apple object to Client
objectOutputStreams[i].writeObject(apple);
objectOutputStreams[i].flush();
```

And here is implementation of **Snake** class. **Apple** class contains only primitive data type variables, so I skip in here.
Snake class contains ArrayList of **Part** object, which also contains only primitive data type variables.

Snake, Apple and Part classes all implements Serializable and has all same serialVersionUID, which is 1L.

```
public class Snake implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ArrayList<Part> body = new ArrayList<Part>();
public int maxLength = 4;
public int level = 1;
public int moveCount = 0;
public boolean keysPressed = false;
public Snake(){
    for(int i = 0;i < maxLength;i++) {
        body.add(new Part());
        body.get(i).x = maxLength - i -1;
        body.get(i).y = 0;
    }
}
public Snake(int x, int y){
    for(int i = 0;i < maxLength;i++) {
        body.add(new Part());
        body.get(i).x = maxLength - i - 1 + x;
        body.get(i).y = y;
    }
}
```

When I check values of ArrayList just before writting to Client, it contains all proper values I want. But when Client receives it, it contains totally different values, which is an ArrayList containing Snake objects filled with initial values.

This is code for Client, receiving objects from Server. In here, **Board** class is class for Graphics (which implements JComponent), and it contains ArrayList of Snake object.

```
//class implementing JComponent for Graphics
Board board = new Board();
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
...
//Tried both ways for reading ArrayList<Snake>. option 1
board.snakes.clear();            
board.snakes.addAll((ArrayList<Snake>)objectInputStream.readObject());

//option 2
//board.snakes = (ArrayList<Snake>)objectInputStream.readObject();
board.apple = (Apple)objectInputStream.readObject();
```

As you can see from the code, I tries 2 ways to put proper values for ArrayList for board object, but they didn't work.

Am I missing something when using objectStream? I'm not fully understanding on using streams in Java, so I need your help on fixing this problem.

Comment: Did you verify that the values you write to your ObjectOutputStream are in fact Snake objects with different values?

Comment: @VGR yes, I checked snake arrayList from server just before sending it with ObjectOutputStream. It had all values I expected.